# VB TimeFormat, timespan, current time

Tags: vb.net, time, timer, basic

First i check if the time is in range 7:50 to 8:35 if is, in label show's message "1st Class in progress"

from 7:50 to 8:35 i have 45 minutes, like a school class.

In textbox i want to show how many time till class end.

Example if show's me the current time is 8:10 . In textbox it needs to show 25:00 ( which means 25 minutes till class end)

Current progress

```
 Private curT As DateTime
 curT = DateTime.Now
 If (curT.Hour = 7 And curT.Minute > 50) Or (curT.Hour = 8 And curT.Minute <= 35) Then
        lblPeriod.Text = "1st Class in progress "
```

i tried using timespan

```
 Dim first As DateTime = CDate("07:50")
        Dim second As DateTime = CDate("08:35")

        Dim current As DateTime
        current = DateTime.Now

        Dim diffBefore As TimeSpan = current - first
        Dim diffAfter As TimeSpan = second - current

        txtPassed.Text = diffBefore.ToString("mm\:ss")
        txtLeft.Text = diffAfter.ToString("mm\:ss")
```

But in txtleft it doesn't countdown to 00:00 ..

Is there any easier way to do this because i have 12 different "school classes"

Comment: A better way to create a those variables is as a TimeSpan type: `Dim first As New TimeSpan(7, 50, 0)`...but is the issue the "countdown" part?  if so you need a timer.

Comment: @Plutonix i know i should use timer which will countdown to 00:00 but the main point is that all this action i do is already in timer tick event. SO im kinda confused how to put timer in a timer. This is my code . I copied to paste bin [Pastebin Code](http://pastebin.com/uynSvUWf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might use a class to track something like this (divining what you want to do from how you are trying to do it).  A class would allow you to internalize some of the TimeSpan stuff, define class start/stops in one place and associate it with a Period/Class name rather than having them littering the code everywhere.

```vb
Public Const PeriodLength = 40

Friend Class ClassPeriod
    Public Property Name As String

    ' as implemented, these could be private and used internally only
    ' But they are props you might need elsewhere
    Public Property StartTime As TimeSpan
    Public Property EndTime As TimeSpan

    Public Sub New(txt As String, stHr As Integer, stMin As Integer)
        Name = txt
        ' internalize the Timespan objects
        StartTime = New TimeSpan(stHr, stMin, 0)
        ' calc end time from start time
        EndTime = StartTime.Add(New TimeSpan(0, PeriodLength, 0))
    End Sub

    ' use a status text return...kind of geared solely for this use though
    Public Function GetStatus() As String
        Dim thisTime = New TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute, 0)

        If ((thisTime >= StartTime) AndAlso (thisTime <= EndTime)) Then
            Return String.Format("[{0}] In Session", Name)
        End If

        If (thisTime > StartTime) Then
            Return String.Format("[{0}] Ended", Name)
        End If

        If (thisTime < StartTime) Then
            Return String.Format("[{0}] starts in {1:hh\:mm} m", Name,
                         (StartTime - thisTime))
            ' StartTime.Subtract(thisTime) results in the same thing... 
            ' VB compiles the above to TS.Subtract
        End If

        ' might never show up since we dont test for betweens
        Return "Between Classes"

    End Function

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Name
    End Function
End Class
```

Now, a collection to hold the definitions.  The names can be "1st Period"... for a generic "school level" tracker, or "Computer Science 101" if used by different students.

```
Friend mySched As New List(Of ClassPeriod)
```

Then populate it:

```
Dim myClPer As ClassPeriod

myClPer = New ClassPeriod("First Period", 7, 0)
mySched.Add(myClPer)
myClPer = New ClassPeriod("Computer Science", 7, 50)
mySched.Add(myClPer)

' or add as you make them:
mySched.Add(New ClassPeriod("Meaning of Life", 8, 40))
mySched.Add(New ClassPeriod("Visual Basic 602", 9, 40))   ' ???
```

(I dont know that all your times are correct, or that I fished the right ones out, but that is not the point, they are easily changed in one spot).  Now, to display the classes status just go thru the list:

```
lblPeriod1.Text = mySched(1).GetStatus()
lblPeriod2.Text = mySched(2).GetStatus()
lblPeriod4.Text = mySched(3).GetStatus()
```

If you stored the label names in a list, you could just iterate:

```
For n As Integer = 0 To mySched.Count - 1
    Controls(lblNames(n)).Text = mySched(n).GetStatus()
Next n
```

The `GetStatus()` would be better as an Enum if the return will ever be evaluated in code.  I would avoid testing a String (`If ..GetStatus() = "Ended"`):

```
Friend PeriodStatus
   InProgress
   Ended
   Pending
End Enum
```

The existing `GetStatus` could then become `GetStatusText` for formatting and displaying info to the user.  The result with a button click standing in for a Timer, a listbox for a bunch of labels:

[image]

*Works on My System*<sup>TM</sup>

Comment: Wow again Plutonix thank you so much for this. Just one question more is there any way i can make this in format   String.Format("[{0}] starts in {1:hh\:mm} m"   like there are "mm:ss" and the second's countdown as in the real time ?

Comment: Seconds are rather silly to display; no one schedules their time to the second.  But yes, just change the format string to include seconds ("hh\:mm\:ss").  To get it to countdown, place the code to update the display in a Timer.  Use a Timer interval appropriate to the granularity of time displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Subtract method of Timespan. Also, for formatting using String.Format.

```
Dim current As DateTime
current = DateTime.Now

Dim diffBefore As TimeSpan = current.Subtract(first)
Dim diffAfter As TimeSpan = second.Subtract(current)

txtPassed.Text = String.Format("{0:mm\:ss}", diffBefore)
txtLeft.Text = String.Format("{0:mm\:ss}", diffAfter)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. My Question is. Is there any way to in the txtleft.text to type something like this txtleft = secondtime - diffbefore ? If i can do this then in my application the txtLeft will decrementing as txtpassed incrementing. That would fix all my problems

Comment: You need to place your code in the onchange event of txtLeft. This will run each time txtleft changes. If you double-click in the txtLeft textbox in design time, it should create an empty onchange event handler for you to put your code into.

Comment: I'm afraid i didn't understood you. Can you please take a look of mine code at pastebin. [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/uynSvUWf)